# Trouble Importing libgdx project from github.

Tags: java, eclipse, github, gradle, libgdx

I built a libgdx project on my desktop which I can build and run properly though I want some friends to work on the project with me and when they import the repository from github the project won't run and it loses the gradle build.

I have tried to use these gradle commands to rebuild the project with no success.

```
   cd/(File path)
   gradle build
   gradle eclipse
```

After I try to do these commands eclipse loses the project file. Even if I copy my master file into the imported directory it doesn't work.

Does anyone has suggestions on how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have no experience with this using `Eclipse` but can't they just pull the repository and in eclipse import a Gradle project? That "should" work seamlessly.

Comment: That worked. I did not think about creating a local repository and pull the project and then import. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with "it loses the gradle build"?

Try using `./gradlew` (or `gradlew` on Windows) instead of `gradle`. The Gradle Wrapper scripts use arcane magic no mortal presumes to understand, but they seem to have their purpose.

Comment: Instead of seperate gradle projects you get one file with all the sub directories listed. Here is a screen shot I took after importing from GitHub to Eclipse. http://imgur.com/I1Ii2jo